# Express-validator not validating after multer function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules, multer

I have a form in my express application for users to enter some text, and also upload 1-3 photos. Im handling the file uploads to my S3 bucket with multer, and I'm validating the rest of the form with express-validator.

This makes my POST route look like:

```
router.post("/list-product", listLimiter, function (req, res) {
  singleUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    // if any multer errors, redirect to form
    if (err) {
      res.redirect(
        "list-product" +
          "?error=Image error, please make sure your file is JPG or PNG"
      );
      return;
    }
    // if no multer errors, validate rest of form
  });
});
```

I'm having issues integrating express-validator. I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now, and I think I'm getting close. My code below will catch the multer error, and it will create a new Product if all the inputs are filled out. So what's happening is my express-validator isn't catching the errors here if (!errors.isEmpty()) { // handle errors and its just skipping it and going straight to else { let product = new Product({. I know this because when I leave the inputs empty, it throws a mongoose error of missing schema paths.

```
router.post("/list-product", listLimiter, function (req, res, next) {
  singleUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    // if any multer errors, redirect to form
    if (err) {
      res.redirect(
        "list-product" +
          "?error=Image error, please make sure your file is JPG or PNG"
      );
      return;
    }
    // if no multer errors, validate rest of form

    body("productName")
      .trim()
      .isLength({ min: 1 })
      .withMessage("Please enter the name of your product"),
      body("productPrice")
        .isNumeric()
        .withMessage("Please enter a valid price"),
      body("productCategory")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage("Please select the category of your product"),
      body("productDescription")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 50 })
        .withMessage("Minimum 50 characters")
        .isLength({ max: 500 })
        .withMessage("Maximum 500 characters"),
      body("businessName")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
      body("website")
        .trim()
        .isURL()
        .withMessage("Please enter the URL for your product or business");

    check("*").escape();

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    let errArray = errors.array();

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.render("list", {
        form: req.body,
        errors: errArray,
        msg: "Please check the form for errors",
        option: req.body.productCategory,
      });
      return;
    } else {
      let product = new Product({
        business: req.body.businessName,
        productName: req.body.productName,
        category: req.body.productCategory,
        price: req.body.productPrice,
        description: req.body.productDescription,
        website: req.body.website,
        imageURL:
          "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
        imageURL2:
          "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
      });
      product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/list-product");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I would truly appreciate any help or advice since I have been stuck on this for a few days and am feeling really stupid!..

I will include one final block of code, this is my express-validator function that works when I'm just validating the text inputs, so I know this approach does work.. I'm just having a real tough time combining it with the multer function

```
exports.list__post = [
  

  body("productName")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please enter the name of your product"),
  body("productPrice")
    .isNumeric()
    .withMessage("Please enter a valid price"),
  body("productCategory")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please select the category of your product"),
  body("productDescription")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 50 })
    .withMessage("Minimum 50 characters")
    .isLength({ max: 500 })
    .withMessage("Maximum 500 characters"),
  body("businessName")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
  body("website")
    .trim()
    .isURL()
    .withMessage("Please enter the URL for your product or business"),

  check("*").escape(),

  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    let errArray = errors.array();

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      console.log(req.body)
      res.render("list", {
        form: req.body,
        errors: errArray,
        msg: "Please check the form for errors",
        option: req.body.productCategory,
      });
      return;
    } else {
      
      let product = new Product({
        business: req.body.businessName,
        productName: req.body.productName,
        category: req.body.productCategory,
        price: req.body.productPrice,
        description: req.body.productDescription,
        website: req.body.website,
        imageURL: "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
        imageURL2:"https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
      });
      product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/list-product");
      });
    }
  },
];
```